# RESTful cookies

Tags: rest, cookies, session-cookies

Is it RESTful and secure to save in a cookie a user identificator (a generated token saved in the database during the login) and send it in the HTTP header on every request to the server?

What kind of cookie is better to use in this case? I guess cookie should expire when browser closes.

Comment: What do you want to use this cookie for?

Comment: I need to know if the user is logged in, and as far as I know, using session variables is not RESTful. How else could I save the state of the current user?

Comment: Saving a generated token on the server side in the DB is expensive in terms of the consumption of the resources. If your requirement doesn't want any compromises interms of security then go for it. Else store the cookies in the client machine.

Comment: What do you mean by store the cookie in the client machine? I am talking about generating a random string for the logged in user, save it in DB and send it back to the client so he could create a cookie in the browser and send it back on every request. In other way I wouldn't know who is the user that sent the token, am I wrong? Thanks for the help

Comment: @Albex89: What you describe is not a cookie. A cookie is a file that is stored on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it RESTful and secure to save in a cookie a user identificator (a
>   generated token saved in the database during the login) and send it in
>   the HTTP header on every request to the server?

No, because storing client session on server side violates the [stateless constraint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) of REST.